# python reading a csv file with panda and multiple filters

Tags: python, pandas, filter

I want to read a csv with python and panda with multiple filters

example csv file with the name passwd.csv:

```
Funktion, Benutzer, Kennwort
user_p, user1, test1
user_f, user2, test2
user, bla, blup
```

python code:

```py
import pandas
d = pandas.read_csv('C:\\tmp\\python\\passwd.csv')
res = d.query('Funktion == "user_f" ')
print (res)
```

this works fine

when I now changed the filter to 2 args, I got an error
pandas.core.computation.ops.UndefinedVariableError: name 'User' is not defined

```py
res = d.query('Funktion == "user_f" ') | d.query('Benutzer == "user2" ')
```

I can´t find the error

Kind regards
Jens

Comment: Is user even a column here? The reason first one worked is because it was a column already. Shouldn't you try benutzer=="user2"

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is a typo, but you're trying to combine two dataframes (returned by `query`) with the `|` operator. It belongs in your expression:

```
res = d.query('Funktion == "user_f" | Benutzer == "user2" ')
```